# embed YouTube video on Xcode programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, youtube

I am a beginner in Xcode and I would like to embed a YouTube video programmatically (without main.storyboard) on Xcode (storyboard).
I wrote this on my view controller but it doesn't work:

```
import UIKit
import youtube_ios_player_helper

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var playerView: YTPlayerView!
 
    
    private let myView: YTPlayerView = {
        let myView = YTPlayerView()
        myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myView.backgroundColor = .link
        return myView
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        playerView?.load(withVideoId: "bsM1qdGAVbU&")
        
        view.addSubview(myView)
        addConstraints()
    }

    private func addConstraints() {
        var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
        
        constraints.append(myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 60))
        constraints.append(myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -60))
        constraints.append(myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -500))
        constraints.append(myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 60))

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about the `youtube_ios_player_helper` you're using, so this is just an educated guess. But I think the problem is that you have both `playerView` and `myView`, which are both `YTPlayerView`s.

1. You call `playerView?.load(withVideoId: "bsM1qdGAVbU&")` but `playerView` is never initialized
2. You initialize `myView`, but then never call `myView.load(withVideoId: "bsM1qdGAVbU&")`

I would get rid of `playerView` and update your viewDidLoad to call `myView.load(withVideoId: "bsM1qdGAVbU&")` instead.